# executing multiple queries in php myadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Whenever i execute multiple queries in "phpMYadmin" it shows result only for the last query.

```
SELECT id FROM customers;
SELECT city FROM customers;
```

it shows only result for the second query i.e "SELECT city FROM customers"

Comment: How do you expect to different results be merged? In your case the first is a number and the second a string.

Comment: Just use [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/), phpMyAdmin is a bloated piece of software from a bygone era, even if it's actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this?

```
SELECT id, city FROM customers
```

Comment: yeah i'm getting result for the above query what u have mentioned but whenever i write a query in the next line, i am not getting result for the first one.

Comment: and i am also getting this error message frequently. **error:** "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."